# child div inherit height of siblingdiv that has height set to 0

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which has two child divs.

One is hidden and holds some text,
the other is a div with a background image.
When I hover over the parent div it shows the hidden text div.

I want the hidden text div to be the same size in height as the backgound image div

If I set the hidden text div size to 100%, the div is too big in height

here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/vg050o67/3/

and the code

```
.portfolioImage {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
}
   .hiddenText {
   position: absolute;
   padding-top:10%;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   text-align:left;
   padding-left:10%;
   z-index:22;
   background-color:#000;
}
 .hiddenText h2 {
   color:#fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight:700;
}
   .hiddenText p {
   color:#fff;
}
   .image_frame {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   z-index:21;
   opacity: 1.0;
   position:relative;
   background-size: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top:100%;
   height: 0;
}
.lowerOpacity {
   opacity:0.9;
}

div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="portfolioImage">
                <div class="footerBar">
                        <h2>Title 1</h2>

                    <p>extra text snippet...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image_frame" style="background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/200/300'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /col-->
    </div>
    <!-- /row-->
</div>
<!-- /container-->

$('.hiddenText').hide();

var formType = '';
$('.portfolioImage').hover(

function () {
    $(this).find(".hiddenText").addClass("lowerOpacity");
    $(this).find('.hiddenText').show();

}, function () {
$(this).find(".hiddenText").removeClass("lowerOpacity");
$(this).find('.footerBar').hide();
});
```

if I set it the height to auto and then use jQuery to get the height of the image div, the returned height is 0

example
http://jsfiddle.net/vg050o67/2/

```
 var bgImageHeight = $(this).find('.image_frame').height();
alert("height=" + bgImageHeight);
$(this).find('.footerBar').css('height', bgImageHeight + 'px');
```

as the image is responsive I cannot hardcode the height of the hidden div

has anybody got any ideas as to how i can get around this, or am I complicating things?

Comment: Perhaps http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/XJdgGy might give you a pointer to do something like this using only html and css

Comment: if you would like to make this an answer, I can accept it as a solution as I have this working using your code retro fitted to my code...brill thanks

Comment: Nice! Thanks, do note that the hover content can't be larger than the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/XJdgGy) might give you a pointer to do something like this using only html and css.

It uses a regular `<img>` tag that's made responsive using the class `img-responsive`. When hovering over the `<img>` the `visibility: hidden` is set which makes the image invisible but still take up space in the document. Hovering also sets `display: block` on the hover content which is positioned absolutely with all positioning properties set to zero so that it will be exactly as large as the image.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;  
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box:hover .box-image {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.box:hover .box-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-text">
          <h1>Header</h1>
          Content
        </div>
        <div class="box-image">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/250" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;` to the `.hiddenText` class. This will make the container's box model respect padding as part of the 100% dimension.

```
.hiddenText {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top:10%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:10%;
    z-index:22;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

**Updated Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vg050o67/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this without javascript.

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vg050o67/9/**

Relevant CSS changes:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}

.portfolioImage 
{
    position: relative;
}

.hiddenText {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0; 
    padding: 10%;    
}

.image_frame 
{
    position:relative;
    background-size: 100%;
    /*maybe you need to alter this*/
    height: 100vh;
}

.hiddenText
{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.portfolioImage:hover .hiddenText
{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to copy the css from the jsFiddle? I deleted some Text class declarations for the answer, as they are not important for it.

Comment: I think other factors where  interfering with the css.